# Why do I get an insufficient permissions error while trying to delete an array element from firestore, yet I can delete the entire document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I have a collection in my firestore named "reports"

one of the fields in the reports map is an array of objects. These objects reference a photo in cloud storage. They look like this (url points to cloud storage):

```
{
   id: uid value
   url: some-url
}
```

my firebase rules are set up like this for the reports document:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /reports/{report} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
      allow delete, update: if request.auth != null &&
      request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
    }
}
```

for some reason, I can delete the entire document if I want to proving that I have delete permission.....but when I attempt to delete an item from the photos array like this:

```
const reportRef = db.collection('reports')
reportRef.doc(activeReport.id).update({
    photos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(photoToDelete)
})
```

I end up with an error stating:

> Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Why? Haven't I given permission to update this document properly?

Comment: Can you try adding the `write` in `allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;` then check again if this will work out? For further reference, check the [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was a bad parameter that was passed in. I needed to pass activeReport not activeReport.id.

This is a misleading error message. I would delete this question but stackoverflow doesn't want me to because an answer has been posted here. Silly.

Answer (score 0):

Go in  Database ->
Rules ->

**For development:**

Change `allow read, write: if` **false;** to **true;**

> Note: It's a quick solution for development purposes only because it will turn off all the security. So, it's not recommended for production.

**For production:**

If authenticated from firebase: `Change allow read, write: if` **false;** to  **request.auth != null;**

Comment: This is a bad solution...it give anyone who is authenticated permission to data even if it's not their data.